# use of OR in javascript object in my case confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

## Question 1

What does `options.left = options.left || _KSM.drawOption.left` means? I know `_KSM.drawOption` is referring to the object (also a function), but how does the `||` operator work here? Does it mean if `_KMS.drawOption.left` is undefinded, assign `options.left` to `options.left`?

## Question 2

Why the author didn't use `this` keyword in this case? I assume it's because in this demo he didn't create an instance, because he just do the calling once. Rigtht? (I've seen a lots of `this` in jquery plugin that's why I'm consufed when the author call the function name instead of this within a function)

Comment: Please post the code here, instead in a screenshot.

Comment: @Eun it's a video I don't have the code.

Comment: Then type the code manually from the screenshot. And please ask only one question per post.

Comment: It means if `options.left` is falsy (`undefined`, `0`,  `false`, ...) then use `_KMS.drawOption.left` instead (`_KMS.drawOption.left` is the default value if no `left` is passed with the options)

Comment: Or in other words, if options.left is null (i.e. not specified) then use the defaults from _KMS.drawOption.left.

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1

This is a way to set a default value to a variable. It actually evaluate the left side and if it is [falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), the variable will be equal to the right side (even if it is also falsy).

That is a bad way of assigning default variable **especially when working with integer**. `0` is considered as falsy, so you will never be able to assign `0` as a left property. Instead, it will always be the default parameter of `_KMS.drawOption` .

## Question 2

We don't have the full code so we can only assume. But my assumption would be that `draw`  is an event, a function bind with `addEventListener`. That mean the context (`this` value) is the target of the event. My guess would be a canvas.

Comment: the author call the function like KSM.draw(..)

Answer (score 0):

Logical Operators in JavaScript work a bit differently than most people expect.

[Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either
>   operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

So instead of the expression resulting in a boolean value, it returns the first value that isn't "falsey". This has the benefit of being a great way to fill in default values in case it is undefined, null, 0, or an empty string.

```
var myObj = { name: 'Josh' };

myObj.age = myObj.age || 33;
```

[Logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both
>   operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

Basically just the opposite. Since any expression that evaluates to false will short circuit the logical check, it can be useful to test for the existence of a field, before trying to use it.

```
var myObj = null;

if(myObj && myObj.person && myObj.person.name === "Josh") // false, no error

var myObj = {};

if(myObj && myObj.person && myObj.person.name === "Josh") // false, no error

var myObj = {person: {}};

if(myObj && myObj.person && myObj.person.name === "Josh") // false, no error

var myObj = {person: {name: "Josh"}};

if(myObj && myObj.person && myObj.person.name === "Josh") // true
```

**However!** Caution should be taken here because in the case of both boolean values `true` or `false` and integer values `0` or anything not `0` you might end up overwriting a legitimate value.

**Question 2:** Not enough context